# Gradle DSL method not found: compile()

Tags: android

I use the IDE android studio 1.0.2 version.

I get the following **error**:

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Error(0,9):   The project 'MiarrayAdapter' may be using a version 
of Gradle that does not contain the method
the built file may be missing a Gradle plugin
```

My file **`build.gradle`** is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

I´ve other file build.gradle (Module app), the code is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.cursoandroid.miarrayadapter"
        minSdkVersion 6
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following from your top-level `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

and also note the comment there:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```